# How to convert a folder with multiple single page PDF's (blueprints) to PNG's using bash or Python?

Tags: python, bash, pdf, png

I have a folder with a couple hundred PDF's that I'd like to convert to PNG images. Every PDF contains a single page with one image (blueprint of a floor).

For this problem I tried using the following bash script I stumbled across:

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file
    do convert -verbose -density 500 -resize 800 "${file}" "${file%.*}.png"
  done
```

This returns the following error:

```
convert: no images defined `./example.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3300.
```

For an example of a PDF I'm trying to convert see this link:

> https://1drv.ms/b/s!Aq9MassPipPcgm7k1q55pDwMxSD4

Anybody know a good way of handling this? I'm also open too Python solutions.

Comment: In parallel with **GNU Parallel** `parallel convert -density 500 -resize 500 {} {.}.png ::: *.pdf`

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer, if I run your code I still get the following error for every file I'm trying to convert:

```convert-im6.q16: no images defined `example.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.```

Comment: Have you maybe got an empty PDF called `example.pdf`?

Comment: Ah no, I just edited the filename in the error code I copied to shorten it down a bit since the original filenames are quite long... But no, only have PDF's with blueprints in the folder.

Comment: Do you have `ghostscript` installed?

Comment: No I haven't, should I look into that?

Comment: Yes, you will need it to read PDFs.

Comment: Okay, thanks, got Ghostscript, converting went successful! As it is now the images contain a lot of blank space, would it also be possible to convert the images and trim the transparent pixels at the same time?

Comment: Try one file with `convert ... xyz.pdf ... -trim result.png`

Comment: Tried the -trim argument, and it seems to be working.

Thanks for all the help so far Mark!

Answer (score 1):

Install pdf2image using:

```
pip install pdf2image
```

Then try this python code:

```
import os
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
for filename in os.listdir('folder'):
    page = convert_from_path('folder/' + filename)
    page[0].save('new_folder/out' + filename + '.png', 'PNG')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I run into this error:

    https://pastebin.com/cuirGnjU

Comment: It looks like you need to install `poppler`/`pdfinfo`.

Comment: Thanks, installed poppler and edited the script as follows: 

    https://pastebin.com/efY59zyS, this works for the first 50 or so PDF’s it processes, until it throws this error:

    https://pastebin.com/L5kEJv7N

and stops the script.

Comment: Maybe one of the PDF's is corrupted or maybe it isn't a PDF at all. I searched about this error and found something about it here:https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165343

Comment: what if the PDFs have multiple pages?